# What is the characteristic of this common emitter diode feedback circuit?

Tags: diodes, bjt

**Given the following circuit and that β=150, I'm asked to find the characteristic of  Vo with respect to Vi:**

[image]

**Vcc is not given but the reverse saturation current of the diode is considered negligible and the diode voltage drop is 0.4 volts when the diode is on.**

I tried solving the problem but I have some gaps.

**Region 1**

We know at first that Vo=Vcc. Therefore as Vi increases we are entering the forward active region. At this point, since Vo is greater than Vin, the diode will be off.

As long as the diode is off, the output voltage is given by :

$$V_o=\frac{V_{cc}-I_c}{2000}=\frac{V_{cc}-150I_b}{2000}$$
Having this, how can I relate Vo to the input voltage? All I can think of is:

$$I_b=\frac{V_i-V_b}{100000}$$

However, what is the base voltage?

**Region 2**

The transistor will remain on until the base voltage is greater than Vo by 0.4 volts. Let's say that Vd is the voltage at the anode of the diode. So, the diode turns on when:

$$U_i-100000\times I_b=V_0+0.4=>U_i-100000\times I_b=\frac{V_{cc}-150I_b}{2000}+0.4$$

This is as far as I could get. I could solve for Ui but even if we consider Vcc a constant value, the base current is unknown.

So, I had a look at the solution manual I have and it seems I've done it almost completely wrong. I don't have the complete solution but this is what I can deduce from the result I saw in the manual:

- The transistor is off until Vin=0.7V.
- The transistor is now in forward active region and the following equation holds: 
  $$I_b=\frac{V_i-0.7}{100000}$$
- The transistor turns on and remains on until we reach an input voltage given by the following calculations:

$$150I_b=I_c=>150\frac{V_i-0.7}{100000}=\frac{V_{cc}-V_o}{2000}$$

According to the above, I have two questions. First, why is the transistor off until 0.7V? And secondly, why is the voltage after the 100000 resistor 0.7V in the f.a. region?

Comment: Transistor is "off" until 0.7V because that's the required voltage for the VBE 'diode' to start to conduct. You need at least 0.7V B->E for any current to conduct at all.

Comment: the voltage across semiconductor junctions is logarithm of the current, with scale factors. For 10:1 more current, the ideal diode voltage will increase 0.058 volts; for 100:1 more current, the ideal diode voltage increases 2*0.058; for 1000:1, expect 3*0.058 = 0..174 volts; for 10,000:1, expect 4*0.058 volts. The "threshold" at 0.7 volts is merely the result of the usual exponential increase of current with voltage (the voltage increasing as log of the current).